# Security - Difference between antivirus and EDR

Tags: security, memory, difference, malware, antivirus

I would like to understand the difference between these 2 tools. 
After a long research, from what I have read, the main difference is that an antivirus cannot acccess the memory. However, I have also read that a DLL injection can be detected by an antivirus even when the process is in the memory.

I have to admit that I'm lost. May I ask your help to understand ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Let my try to explain they way I understand it
Antivirus is a program which can detect viruses (in fact all categories of malware) and prevent them. But there are threats today which can not be said as mere viruses. It may include device control, log analysis and intrusion detection, data loss prevention etc. You keep adding features and you get a new beast to whom you can not call anti virus. you need a new business term which EDR endpoint threat detection and response. All AVs scan memory and try to defend against DLL injection by making of signatures or heuristics and EDR also must do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.